# How do i reshape an RGB image in the form of a numpy array into it's channels?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, rgb

I have an RGB array of an image of the shape `(x, y, 3)`.
How do i separate it into it's separate RGB channels?
for example, if i had the array (of shape `(2, 2, 3)`):

```
[0 1 2] [3 4 5]
[6 7 8] [9 10 11]
```

how do i turn it into the arrays:

```
r = [0, 3, 6, 9]
g = [1, 4, 7, 10]
b = [2, 5 ,8, 11]
```

i tried to do:

```
array.reshape(3, x, y)
r = array[0]
g = array[1]
b = array[2]
```

but it puts the values in in the same order they were in before instead of the order i want. that would turn the array i used for the last example into the arrays:

```
r = [0, 1, 2, 3]
g = [4, 5, 6, 7]
b = [8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Don't you want 3 (2,2) shaped arrays, preserving the x,y shape?  `r=data[...,0]; g=data[...,1]; b=data[...,2]`

Comment: yes, you're correct. probably should have added that in. Although it is pretty trivial to split a (3,2,2) array into 3 (2,2) arrays

Comment: Another `r,g,b=np.split(data, 3, axis=2)`.   If using `transpose`, consider the difference between `data.transpose()` and `data.transpose(2,0,1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose the array and assign it to `r, g, b`:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]])

r, g, b = np.transpose(data)

print(r)
print(g)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[0 3 6 9]
[ 1  4  7 10]
[ 2  5  8 11]
```